# RegExp to find specific string with random characters in between

Tags: php, regex, base64

I'm not even hopeful that this is possible. I'm looking for the string "base64_decode" in PHP files (yes this is to clean up a site that has been hacked). The problem is that this hacker has "hidden" the string like so:

```
'ba'.'se'.(32*2).'_d'.'eco'.'de'
or
'b'.'as'.'e6'.'4_d'.'ec'.'ode';
```

And a few other ways.

Therefore I would like to search for the string "decode" or "base" ignoring all the characters in between each letter. I understand this would be very CPU intensive (especially when you have a few hundred MB of files to go through (yes, he hide the code in other files like a GIF image).

Is that even possible?

I know about Sucuri for online website, but if you have other suggestion of tools to scan the files and discover other hacks I'm interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?:b[^a-zA-Z]*?a[^a-zA-Z]*?s[^a-zA-Z]*?e)|(?:d[^a-zA-Z]*?e[^a-zA-Z]*?c[^a-zA-Z]*?o[^a-zA-Z]*?d[^a-zA-Z]*?e)
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pG1kU1/17